# scipy.optimize.newton gives TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Tags: python, function, typeerror, newtons-method

My whole program is right (I've checked at various stages). The highlighted line in this module, however, returns the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

I don't know why this is happening. `funcPsat` returns float value. I would appreciate any useful advice!

```
import scipy.optimize.newton as newton

def Psat(self, T):
    pop= self.getPborder(T)
    boolean=int(pop[0])
    P1=pop[1]
    P2=pop[2]
    if boolean:
        Pmin = min([P1, P2])
        Pmax = max([P1, P2])
        if Pmin > 0.0: 
            Pguess = 0.5*(Pmin+Pmax) 
        else:
            Pguess=0.5*Pmax
        solution = newton(self.funcPsat, Pguess, args=(T))   #error in this line
        return solution
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error traceback? What is `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that, per the documentation

> **`args`:** *tuple, optional*
>
> Extra arguments to be used in the function call.

the `args` argument should be a `tuple`.

Just putting parentheses won't do it; the syntax for tuples is the comma. For example:

```
>>> T = 0
>>> type((T))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((T,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

Try:

```
solution = newton(self.funcPsat, Pguess, args=(T,))
                                              # ^ note comma
```